# Why is Tomcat 8 not persisting sessions to the datastore immediately after creation?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm running Tomcat 8 and I'm setting up a custom session manager for session persistence to Amazon DynamoDB. I'm using the [AWS Java session manager library](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-tomcat-session-manager.html) for Tomcat-DynamoDB and it seems to be working fine (although my question is not specific to this library). I'm doing development and running tests with just a single Tomcat instance (no cluster).

There is some unusual behavior that I don't understand. When I login to my site, a new session is created. Immediately after I've logged, I can send requests to my web server and do things, all of which require a valid session (which I have).

The problem is that immediately after I've logged in, the new session entry is not immediately persisted to the datastore (DynamoDB). In fact, every time a new session is created, I've observed that it will take between 30 seconds and 1 minute, sometimes more, before the session entry appears in DynamoDB.

Now, obviously the reason that I've been able to make requests that require authentication immediately after logging in is because the single Tomcat instance is caching session data somehow, and then presumably persisting sessions to the datastore at it's leisure.

My concern is that when I'm using a cluster of instances in an auto-scaling group with a load balancer, if sessions are not immediately persisted to the datastore on creation, then subsequent requests immediately after login could fail authentication. If 2 machines are in the cluster, machine A handles the login and caches the newly created session, then machine B handles a subsequent request, the request will fail because machine B doesn't know about the session and it won't be in the datastore yet.

Invalidating requests, on the other hand, **immediately** deletes the session from the datastore.

I should also mention that I am aware of the `maxIdleBackup` option, which is currently set to 30 seconds. From the docs for this option:

> The time interval (in seconds) since the last access to a session before it is eligible for being persisted to the session store...

I don't mind session data not being **updated** immediately (like last access time), if fact I don't mind upping this to 1 or 2 minutes. But immediately persisting the session on creation seems like a crucial bit of functionality that Tomcat is not providing.

Finally, I should also mention that I've gone through all the source code for the session manager library I'm using (for persistence to DynamoDB, it's only a few classes) and it essentially only handles the conversion process from a Tomcat session to DynamoDB item and vice versa, plus expired session reaping etc. So, this seems to me like a Tomcat issue, unless I've misunderstood something.

---

I've run down through the [clustering how-to](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) and it seems that it's aimed at managing a cluster of machines in such a way that in-memory session data is continuously replicated and kept in sync among all the machines in the cluster. This is not I want, since I'm using a remote database (DynamoDB) so that each Tomcat instance does not have to know or care about any other node in the cluster. Each node has their own session cache and falls back to / updates the database if necessary.

The docs do talk about the built-in `BackupManager` as an option for a `<Manager>`, but my understanding is that it's responsible for backing up session data to one specific machine.

I've actually managed to find a work-around to solve the problem I'm having of new sessions not being immediately persisted to the database. I'll add an answer with the details so that this question doesn't turn into a monstrosity.

Comment: Have you read the [clustering-howto](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that I'm using using that solves the problem for me. I guess it could be considered a hack, but it's working and I don't see any problems doing it (but if anyone has concerns, please let me know).

Basically, I'm just forcing the session save right after it's been created. The problem was actually finding a way to get hold of a reference to the session managers datastore, since the servlet API does not expose access to it. So, first I have to get a reference to the session manager using reflection:

```
private static PersistentManagerBase getSessionManager(HttpSession session) {
    StandardSession stdSession;
    try {
        Field facadeSessionField = StandardSessionFacade.class.getDeclaredField("session");
        facadeSessionField.setAccessible(true);
        stdSession = (StandardSession) facadeSessionField.get(session);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("Error attempting to retrieve session manager => " 
                + e.getMessage() + " -- the new session has been created anyway, just not immediately persisted to the database");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return (PersistentManagerBase) stdSession.getManager();
}
```

...then I can get a reference to the `Store` object.

```
Store store = manager.getStore();
```

Unfortunately, the `Store.save(Session session)` call (which persists the session to the database) will only accept an object that implements the `Session` interface. `HttpSession` does not, so you have to create a `StandardSession` object which is essentially a copy of your new `HttpSession` object, like this:

```
private static Session createStandardSession(HttpSession newSession, Manager manager) {
    StandardSession stdSession = new StandardSession(manager);
    stdSession.setId(newSession.getId());
    stdSession.setCreationTime(newSession.getCreationTime());
    stdSession.setValid(true);
    stdSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(newSession.getMaxInactiveInterval());
    Enumeration<String> attrNames = newSession.getAttributeNames();
    while ( attrNames.hasMoreElements() ){
        String attrName = attrNames.nextElement();
        stdSession.setAttribute(attrName, newSession.getAttribute(attrName));
    }
    return stdSession;
}
```

So, to put it all together:

```
HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);
PersistentManagerBase manager = getSessionManager(newSession);
if (manager != null) {
    manager.getStore().save( createStandardSession(newSession, manager) );
}
```

You need the Tomcat library `catalina.jar` to access the classes:

- org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession
- org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase